# update a mocked object in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I have a mocked object created as follows:

```
    with patch('requests.get') as request:
      self.request = request
      self.request.session = MockSession()
      self.request.cookies = {}
```

How can it be updated through another function

Comment: How are values updated in `set_nonce`?

Comment: @asaf92: Updated the method in my question

Comment: Where do you do the patching? Are you using `unittest` or `pytest`? Note that the patching is reverted after you get out of scope - depending on your structure, this may be your problem.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I am not sure I understand how to patch it in. I am using unittest. Could you may be share how would I patching in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save a patched object, you have to start and stop patching manually. If you use the context manager (e.g. `with patch`), the patching will be reverted at exiting the scope.
Here is what you can do:

```py
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      self.patcher = patch('requests.get')  # returns the patcher object
      self.request = self.patcher.start()  # returns the patched object
      self.request.session = MockSession()
      self.request.cookies = {}

    def tearDown(self):
        sef.patcher.stop()

    def test_03_set_nonce(self):
        self.web_session.set_nonce(self.request)
        self.assertTrue(len(self.request.cookies) > 0, 'set_nonce failed.')
```

Note that I didn't check the actual test - this depends on your application logic.

You can also do the patching directly in the test:

```py
    @patch('requests.get')
    def test_03_set_nonce(self, request):
        request.session = MockSession()
        request.cookies = {}
        self.web_session.set_nonce(request)
        self.assertTrue(len(request.cookies) > 0, 'set_nonce failed.')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Have just updated what my test class looks like now but the request.cookies still fails

Comment: You are calling `set_nonce` with a mock object - `addCookie` will not do anything except record the call. If you want to test the behavior of the function, you cannot mock it.

Comment: okay. what should I be doing here in that case? and for what case should the mock be used here? I feel a bit lost with it

Comment: Well, I don't know your code, but you have to clarify what do you want to test and what do you want to mock. Maybe you don't want to mock `request.get` (which you name `request`, which is a bit confusing), but only the session? Generally it would help to show the code which you are trying to test (or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), and clarify what you want to test.

Comment: Added more details in the question. please look at Edit 3. I have custom objects for testing the behaviour.I am trying to use mocks here wherever I can so that I do not write a lot of custom objects to test the behaviour. I am trying to understand wherever mocks can be used for this example

Comment: So I understand your test code in edit 3 is the working code, and you just want to refactor it using `mock.patch`? I may have a closer look later today, have to run now.

Comment: That's right. I am trying to refactor it to use mocking/patching wherever possible. Sure, that would be great. thanks much. Look forward to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492346/integrating-mock-and-patch-in-a-python-unit-test I have shared minimum reproducible code here in this question.