# integrating mock and patch in a python unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a class with a few methods that I am writing unit test cases for. For minimum reproducible example, I am attaching 3 of the methods from that class:

**Class that I am testing methods of :**

```
class WebViewLincSession(object):
    def renew_session_id(self, request):
            session = request.getSession()
            new_session_key = self.get_token()
            while new_session_key in session.guard.sessions:  # just in case the key is already used
                new_session_key = self.get_token()
            session.guard.sessions.pop(session.uid)  # remove the current session
            session.uid = new_session_key  # update the key
            session.guard.sessions[new_session_key] = session  # add session back with the new key
            request.addCookie(session.guard.cookieKey, new_session_key, path='/', secure=True, httpOnly=True)  # send updated cookie value
    def set_nonce(self, request):
        '''
        create a nonce value and send it as cookie
        '''
        if self._nonce_key is None:
            if self._NONCE_FOR_TEST:
                self._nonce_key = 'ecnon_for_test'
            else:
                self._nonce_key = 'ecnon_' + self.get_token()
            
        new_nonce_value = self.get_token()
        while new_nonce_value in self._nonce:  # just in case the value is already used
            new_nonce_value = self.get_token()
        
        now = time()
        stay_alive = now + self._STAY_ALIVE

        # reset timeout value for all existing nonces         
        for key in self._nonce.keys():
            if self._nonce[key] > stay_alive:
                self._nonce[key] = stay_alive
        
        self._nonce[new_nonce_value] = now + self._NONCE_TIMEOUT
        
        request.addCookie(self._nonce_key, new_nonce_value, path='/', secure=True, httpOnly=True)  # send updated cookie value
        
        return new_nonce_value


    def get_valid_nonce(self):
        now = time()
        return [nonce for nonce in self._nonce.keys() if self._nonce[nonce] > now]
```

**My test class looks like following:**

```
from __future__ import (division, absolute_import, with_statement)

from time import sleep

from mock import patch, MagicMock, mock, Mock
from requests.sessions import Session
from twisted.trial.unittest import TestCase

from viewlinc.webserver.web_viewlinc_session import WebViewLincSession


class MockGuard(object):
    '''Mock guard object for testing'''
    def __init__(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        ''' class constructor
        '''
        super(MockGuard, self).__init__(*ags, **kwargs)
        self.cookieKey = 'test_cookie_key'
        self.sessions = {'_test_session_': {}}

class MockSession(object):
    '''Mock session object for testing'''
    def __init__(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        ''' class constructor
        '''
        super(MockSession, self).__init__(*ags, **kwargs)
        self.guard = MockGuard()
        self.uid = '_test_session_'

class MockRequest(object):
    '''Mock Request object for testing'''
    def __init__(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        ''' class constructor
        '''
        super(MockRequest, self).__init__(*ags, **kwargs)
        self.session = MockSession()
        self.cookies = {}
  
    def getSession(self):
        ''' returns session object
        '''
        return self.session
          
    def addCookie(self, key, value, path='/', secure=True, httpOnly=True, expires=None):
        ''' add/replace cookie
        '''
        self.cookies[key] = {
            'value': value,
            'path': path,
            'secure': secure,
            'httpOnly': httpOnly,
            'expires': expires
        }
          
    def getCookie(self, key):
        ''' retrieve a cookie
        '''
        cookie = self.cookies.get(key, {'value': None})
        return cookie['value']

class WebViewLincSessionTests(TestCase):
    '''Test WebViewLincSession methods'''

    def __init__(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        ''' class constructor
        '''
        super(WebViewLincSessionTests, self).__init__(*ags, **kwargs)
        self.request = MockRequest()
        self.web_session = WebViewLincSession()
    


    def test_02_renew_session_id(self):
        '''Test renew_session_id
        '''
        self.web_session.renew_session_id(self.request)
        session = self.request.session
        return self.assertTrue(session.uid != '_test_session_' and session.uid in session.guard.sessions, 'renew_session_id failed')

    def test_03_set_nonce(self):
        '''Test set_nonce
        '''
        self.web_session.set_nonce(self.request)
        
        return self.assertTrue(len(self.request.cookies) > 0, 'set_nonce failed.')


    def test_04_get_valid_nonce(self):
        '''Test get_valid_nonce
        '''
        # use a clean session
        web_session = WebViewLincSession()
        web_session.set_nonce(self.request)
        web_session.set_nonce(self.request)
        valid_nonce = web_session.get_valid_nonce()

        self.assertTrue(len(valid_nonce) == 2, 'Expecting 2 valid nonces.')
        
        sleep(16)
        valid_nonce = web_session.get_valid_nonce()
        
        return self.assertTrue(len(valid_nonce) == 1, 'Expecting 1 valid nonce.')
```

**What I want:**

I would like to use mock/patch in my test class where-ever possible. That probably means that `MockGuard`, `MockSession` and `MockRequest` be replaced with instances of mock. I would like to see how can this be refined to use mock/patch from `unittest` package in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, trying to give you an idea. In the tests, you have created a fake `addCookie` method for your tests, but you only use it to check how `addCookie` has been called. So, for example, your test 3 and 4 you could rewrite:

```py
   def test_03_set_nonce(self):
        request = mock.Mock()
        self.web_session.set_nonce(request)
        # we only need to know that it was called once
        request.addCookie.assert_called_once()

   def test_04_get_valid_nonce(self):
        request = mock.Mock()
        web_session = WebViewLincSession()
        web_session.set_nonce(request)
        web_session.set_nonce(request)
        # check that addCookie it has been called twice
        self.assertEqual(2, request.addCookie.call_count)
        
        valid_nonce = web_session.get_valid_nonce()
        ... # the rest is not dependent on mocks
```

In other tests, you may have also to check the arguments used in the calls. You always have to define what you are actually want to test, and then setup your mocks so that only that functionality is tested.

Note also that in some cases it may make sense to use extra mock classes like you have done - there is nothing wrong with that, if that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks  much for sharing. But what I am trying to test sometimes involves checking for the values that i have on session, cookies as well.  For example, I have just updated my question with method set_nonce, renew_session_id-  test case test_03_set_nonce, test_02_renew_session_id are checking for values on session as well. How would I handle that? @MrBran Bremen

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't? As I wrote, there is nothing wrong with using custom mock objects if it suites your needs. As you use them only as arguments, there is also no need to patch anything. So my question is now - what is wrong with your tests?

Comment: I believe not being able to mock those objects would lead to writing a-lot of code in test class itself so I would ideally like to mock/patch stuff that I can. I understand that the manually created mock_objects work for me here but I am also trying to understand if I can really use mock from the package to refine the test cases I have defined. I can decide to stick with what I have but I am trying to see my options with mock and check if I benefit from it, if it refines my code and fits in the test cases. Also, I believe it will help me understand the right use cases for it in future.

Comment: and is it for sure that the mock instances can not be used to verify/test any changes in values? For example: mocking request object using request = mock.Mock() and adding a value to request.cookies ={'hello':'test'} will not work for testing?

Comment: Mocks only collect the call arguments. As long as it is sufficient for you to know the calls and call arguments, this will work, otherwise you have to do more (like writing your own collector mock as you did).